# accessing objects of xml layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-layout

I have an activity (`MainActivity.java`) in which content view is like this

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.standalone_example);
```

my standalone_example.xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<com.abc.view.PageCurlView
    android:id="@+id/dcgpagecurlPageCurlView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/page1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am done some work in `PageCurlView.java` now I want to access objects and variables of `PageCurlView.java` in my `MainActivity.java`, I am searching for hours but couldnt find any answer, any suggestions thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the inflated PageCurlView using findViewById() in your activity.  In a method in your activity:

```
PageCurlView mPageCurlView = (PageCurlView) findViewById(R.id.dcgpagecurlPageCurlView1);
```

You can then call methods or access public variables on mPageCurlView.  Please note that setContentView() must be called first in your activity before you can use findViewById().

Comment: So after setContentView use findViewById and you can start calling methods on the PageCurlView object.  Did this answer your question?